# Calling function when List Group Header Change in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch

I want to call a function when the group function is changed when we scroll in list.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/p36

Basically, you need to override List's handlePinnedHeader. Instead of console.log you can put fireEvent or your custom code